# How to configure Frag3 to treat packages as Windows packages on a specyfic hosts?

Tags: linux, snort

For example I have host addresses: 3.3.3.3 and 3.3.3.33. How to configure Frag3 preprocessor to treat packages that goes to those adressess like/with a typical Windows defragmentation politics?

Answer (score 2):

See the snort manual on [frag3](http://manual.snort.org/node17.html#SECTION00321000000000000000). You are looking for the "policy" option. If you want snort to treat just these IP addresses as windows you can do something like the following in your snort.conf:

```
preprocessor frag3_engine: policy Windows bind_to [3.3.3.3/32, 3.3.3.33/32]
```